# Cannot run Python script using IDLE 3.9 from Finder

Tags: macos, big-sur, python

When I try to run a Python script I have from Finder, I get the following error (see image):

[image: Cannot open files in the "Python Script" format]

Anyone have any ideas what is going on with this? Thank you!

Comment: Very weird. And the file is a valid python script? And IDLE launches correctly otherwise? And you don't have other apps named IDLE that might be competing?

Comment: @benwiggy Yep, it's valid and IDLE launches correctly otherwise (I can run this script through IDLE still). IDLE won't launch any Python scripts. I should have noted that it is an M1 chip but I haven't seen anything to indicate that IDLE doesn't work with M1.